# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit' error problem

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to add an image to the screen but i keep getting this error:

> #### AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'

here is my code :

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

myscreen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
myscreen = pygame.display.set_caption(("Mini game"))
icon = pygame.image.load("images\space.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerx = 200
playery = 200

def player():
    myscreen.blit(playerImg, (playerx, playery))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in the first couple of instructions of your code:

> ```py
> myscreen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
> myscreen = pygame.display.set_caption(("Mini game"))
> ```

The return value of [`pygame.display.set_caption()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_caption) is `None`. The surface which is associated to the window is returned by [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), but it is covered because the return value of `pygame.display.set_caption()` is assigned to `myscreen`. It has to be:

```py
myscreen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Mini game"))
```

---

Furthermore you have to update the display at the end of the application loop, by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

myscreen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Mini game"))
icon = pygame.image.load("images\space.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerx = 200
playery = 200

def player():
    myscreen.blit(playerImg, (playerx, playery))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player() 
    pygame.display.flip() # <--- this is missing
```